# Divide a frame from corner to corner

Tags: beamer, mini-frames, frame, customize

I want to divide a frame in beamer from corner to corner having images on both sides. It should look something like the image attached. I have this idea, but I'm completely unaware of how to do this. Please help me out.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use tikz:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}

% trick taken from https://topanswers.xyz/tex?q=1989
\tikzset{
    use page relative coordinates/.style={
        shift={(current page.south west)},
        x={(current page.south east)},
        y={(current page.north west)}
    },
}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{frame}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay,use page relative coordinates]
    \draw[blue,thick] (current page.north west) -- (current page.south east);
    \node at (0.2,0.2) {\includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image-duck}};
    \node at (0.8,0.8) {\includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image-duck}};    
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame} 
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Can it be possible to add a Text line above the lower image?

Comment: @user84456 Sure, you can add tikz node with whatever text you like `\node at (0.5,0.5) {some text};`

Comment: One more thing, Can I fill the upper and lower portions with different colours?

Comment: @user84456  `\fill[red] (current page.south east) -| (current page.north west) -- cycle;\fill[blue] (current page.south east) |- (current page.north west) -- cycle;`  -- You should really ask a new question if you have a new question

Comment: Thank you very much. It was a great help

Comment: @user84456 You're welcome!